Unable to conduct sudo apt-get update command on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Here is the command I am calling followed by the errors.
ubuntu@ip-10-0-2-185:~$ sudo apt-get update
Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (2600:1f18:5c55:4c02:b55:260f:8030:b812). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) 
Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (2600:1f18:5c55:4c02:7669:c120:50a2:9af4). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (2600:1f18:5c55:4c03:edb9:571f:f204:4ac8). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (2600:1f18:5c55:4c04:b8fe:122c:bb55:6b84). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) 
Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (2600:1f18:5c55:4c05:17c8:ad29:43bf:eb48). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) 
Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (2600:1f18:5c55:4c00:2637:a32b:ccef:30d5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (2600:1f18:5c55:4c00:7447:9a97:fa56:cd92). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) 
Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (2600:1f18:5c55:4c00:e093:e2e5:23b4:529f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) 
Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (2600:1f18:5c55:4c01:32a9:41b2:cfa3:904a). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) 
Cannot initiate the connection to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (2600:1f18:5c55:4c01:ed0c:fdfa:1470:afc0). - connect (101: Network is unreachable).    Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (52.207.133.243), connection timed out 
Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (54.87.19.168), connection timed out 
Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (54.144.148.213), connection timed out 
Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (54.165.17.230), connection timed out 
Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (3.87.126.146), connection timed out 
Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (3.209.10.109), connection timed out 
Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (18.232.150.247), connection timed out 
Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (34.201.250.36), connection timed out 
Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (34.237.137.22), connection timed out 
Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:8080 (52.91.65.63), connection timed out


Boot, login,
Make sure you have Internet access Network is unreachable <- says you don't have it
(ipv6 problem?).
If it still doesn't work; then hit the Super (Win) key and start typing software and you should see:

Select the blue icon, hit enter; a window should appear with a tab named Ubuntu software selected.
Just below the middle there is a text saying Download from:  - to the right of it; select something other than what you have there currently; then simply redo your update attempts.
